# How to read the entity from Javax.ws.rs.Response -jersey 1.18

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to do something like this

```
Response response = webclient.post(SomeReqString);
```

This response  is from `javax.ws.rs.Response` from jersey 1.18

How should I get the `List<customobject>` from above response?

There is no readEntity method in jersey 1.x and also there is no generic type class in jersey 1.x.

Due to some restriction, I cannot use `webresource` and `Clientresponse`.

The only useful method I found is `response.getEntity()` (it does not accept any parameter)

How should I use this to get the List?

Comment: I would recommend posting some more code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `response.readEntity(String.class)` is a safe way to get the response-body as a string. You can then use another library to deserialize this string back into a list, depending on how it's formatted.